# Docker conditionally exposing port for debugger

Tags: docker, docker-compose, remote-debugging, vscode-debugger

I would like to conditionally open a debug port on one of the services in our `docker-compose.yml` file when we want to run the debugger.

```
services:
  service-one:
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "1234:1234" # debugger port - conditionally allow based on env var or cmd line

  service- two:
    ...
  service-three:
    ...
```

We are running all of these services but for `service-one` we want to conditionally open 1234 if it's debug mode.

Can that be done by passing a command line in `docker-compose up` ?
`docker-compose up --env-file .env.debug`

Or can we do it some other way like using build stages in our `Dockerfile` and somehow targeting debugging vs non-debugging ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably do this with [multiple Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files).  You can have a normal `docker-compose.yml` that sets up the service as you'd normally run it:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  service-one:
    image: registry.example.com/service/one:${SERVICE_ONE_TAG:latest}
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      - SERVICE_TWO_URL=http://service-two:3000/
  service-two: { ... }
```

And then a second `docker-compose.debug.yml` that has only the settings specific to the debugger setup.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  service-one:
    ports:
      - '1234:1234'
    environment:
      - DEBUG_PORT=1234
```

Now if you run

```bash
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.debug.yml up
```

(and you need both `-f` options, with every `docker-compose` command, while you're using this setup) then it will take the `image:` from the first file, and combine the `ports:` and `environment:` from both files.  When you don't need the debugger, remove the `-f docker-compose.debug.yml` option and it will only use the settings from the base file.

Comment: I tried this and it works great - I did need to add a `volumes` section in `docker-compose.debug.yml` file - for some reason I guess having a second docker-compose file you still need to map the volume to the right place

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve it using docker-compose profiles. Here's an excerpt from compose documentation

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  frontend:
    image: frontend
    profiles: ["frontend"]

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      - db
    profiles:
      - debug

  backend:
    image: backend

  db:
    image: mysql
```

Here the services frontend and phpmyadmin are assigned to the profiles frontend and debug respectively and as such are only started when their respective profiles are enabled.

Services without a profiles attribute will always be enabled, i.e. in this case running docker-compose up would only start backend and db.

Valid profile names follow the regex format of [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+.

Note

The core services of your application should not be assigned profiles so they will always be enabled and automatically started.

Enabling profiles
To enable a profile supply the --profile command-line option or use the COMPOSE_PROFILES environment variable:

$ docker-compose --profile debug up
$ COMPOSE_PROFILES=debug docker-compose up
The above command would both start your application with the debug profile enabled. Using the docker-compose.yml file above, this would start the services backend, db and phpmyadmin.

> So essentially have 2 containers for the same service with desired number of ports and start docker-compose using appropriate profiles

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/